# How to use vuex with defineCustomElement in vue 3.2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

In Vue version 3.2 we can define custom elements using new future [defineCustomElement](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#definecustomelement)

How I can use (connect) store (vuex) with defineCustomElement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
// App.ce.vue
<template>
  <pre>{{ state }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import store from './store';

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = store.state;

    return { state };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: How you connect this store to your custom element?

Comment: How to create method which do any actions using vuex. Example vuex actions or commits? How to dispatch actions? If you have demo project can you share you example?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-grass-slq28

Comment: In my case too work this example but not work dispatch store actions. How I can correctly dispatch vuex actions in custom element? @tvanbeek

Comment: I updated the example for you to show both a working Action and Mutation.

Comment: I tried add css styles in custom element but does not work for me. Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-swirles-kylbd). Do you know how add correctly styles inside c.e?

Comment: Its a bit finicky to get working, I agree. But rename your component to *.ce.vue and make sure you have the correct version of @vitejs/plugin-vue@^1.4.0 or vue-loader@^16.5.0 and it should work. Please read the docs carefully: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/web-components.html#sfc-as-custom-element.